# In XML View How to bind items with dynamic values/model properties for the parameters

Tags: sapui5

To restrict the number of items shown in the list, you can pass 2 parameter startIndex,length like this

```
<List items = "{path: 'model>/Invoices', length: 3, startIndex: 0}">
```

Can we make the length come from model `length:'model>/property'` or is it possible to pass js variable into xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the List supports a "growing" feature where you can surely use binding

see https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.List/sample/sap.m.sample.ListGrowing

If you really, really  want to cut of more than x Rows, you could set a limit on your Model.
see [setSizeLimit](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.model.Model%23methods/Summary)